# merge elements in a Spark RDD under custom condition

Tags: mapreduce, apache-spark

How can I merge elements in a Spark RDD under custom condition?

Suppose there is a RDD[Seq[Int]], where some Seq[Int] in this RDD contain overlapping elements. The task is to merge all overlapping Seq[Int] in this RDD, and store the result into a new RDD.

For example, suppose RDD[Seq[Int]] = [[1,2,3], [2,4,5], [1,2], [7,8,9]], the result should be [[1,2,3,4,5], [7,8,9]].

Since RDD[Seq[Int]] is very large, I cannot do it in driver program. Is it possible to get it done using distributed groupBy/map/reduce, etc?

Comment: @maasg I think this problem could be transformed into computing all connected graphs formed by elements in RDD[Seq[Int]], since the merge condition (two Seq[Int] have overlapping integers) denotes connectivity between two Seq[Int]

Comment: Indeed that would be an idea. I see you're new to SO. Welcome!. It's part of the 'house rules' to show your own efforts in solving a problem, hence the previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

Finally worked it out by myself.

This problem can be transformed into computing all connected components formed by elements in RDD[Seq[Int]], since the merge condition (two Seq[Int] have overlapping integers) denotes connectivity between two Seq[Int].

The basic idea is:

1. Give each element in RDD[Seq[Int]] an unique key (.zipWithUniqueId)
2. Group integers in Seq[Int] by the generated key, thus integers that appear in multiple Seq[Int] will have the corresponding key grouped together
3. Generate a RDD graph, where the edges are key pairs from the same group in Step 2
4. Use GraphX to compute connected components, and join the results

   ```
   val sets = Seq(Seq(1,2,3,4), Seq(4,5), Seq(1,2,3), Seq(6,7,8), Seq(9,10), Seq(7,9))
   val rddSets = sc.parallelize(sets)
                   .zipWithUniqueId
                   .map(x => (x._2, x._1)).cache()
   val edges = rddSets.flatMap(s => s._2.map(i => (i, s._1)))
                      .groupByKey.flatMap(g => {
                          var first = g._2.head
                          for (v <- g._2.drop(1)) yield {
                            val pair = (first, v)
                            first = v
                            pair
                           }
                      }).flatMap(e => Seq((e._1, e._2), (e._2, e._1)))

   val vertices = Graph.fromEdgeTuples[Long](edges, defaultValue = 0)
                       .connectedComponents.vertices
   rddSets.join(vertices).map(x => (x._2._2, x._2._1))
          .reduceByKey((s1, s2) => s1.union(s2).distinct)
          .collect().foreach(x => println (x._2.toString()))
   ```